# como colocar formato de fecha en javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Cree esta tabla en apps script, cuando me impre las fechas en HTML me las imprime en ingles, me gustaria colocarle un formato, o que sea en español.

como se ve:Tue Nov 29 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (VET)
como quisiera que se viera: 29/11/2022

```
function crearTabla(){
  var data = getData()
  var tabla = '<table class="tabla"><tr></tr>\n';
  
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    tabla += '<tr>';
    for(var j = 1; j < data[1].length; j++){
      tabla += '<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>'
    }
    tabla += '</tr>\n';
  }
  tabla += '</table>';
  return tabla;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes extraer cada dato de la fecha y darle el formato a tu gusto de la siguiente forma en tu segundo `for`:

```
for(var j = 1; j < data[1].length; j++){
 const date = new Date(data[i][j]);
 const day = date.getDate();
 const month = date.getMonth() + 1; // se le suma 1 porque los meses se obtienen desde 0
 const year = date.getFullYear();

 tabla += '<td>' + day + '/' + month + '/' + year + '</td>'
}
```

Comment: Una mejora posible, sería agregar algo como .toString().padStart(2, '0')) para agregar ceros a la izquierda